# how to exchange text on two buttons on other button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have three buttons btn1 having title 'Up' and btn2 having title 'Down'.
and after click on third button btn3, title of btn1 and btn2 gets change as btn1 having title 'Down' and btn2 having title 'Up'. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

```
-(IBAction)thirdButtonClick:(id)sender
{
   if (!self.isChanged)
   {
     self.isChanged = YES;
     [btn1 setTitle:@"Down" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btn2 setTitle:@"Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   else
   {
     self.isChanged = NO;
     [btn1 setTitle:@"Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btn2 setTitle:@"Down" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }

}
```

**Update** : If you click third button continuously, It will change accordingly.

Comment: @Bhagyashree mahajan I think , you are beginner to IOS, that's why we posting answer to you. Just google before post question to stackoverflow. Happy learning :).

Comment: Yes. i will google before posting question.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hasn't been tested but this should work.

```
@interface

Class : Superclass 
{
    Bool flip;
}

@implementation

-(IBAction)thirdButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    [btn1 setTitle:[self titleForBool:flip] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    flip = !flip;

    [btn2 setTitle:[self titleForBool:flip] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(NSString*)titleForBool:(BOOL)flip
{
    return flip ? @"Up" : @"Down";
}
```